# How do i setOnClickListener on RecyclerView on Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

i want to put setOnClickListener on the recyclerview that i follow on a tutorial, the problem is, i don't know where to put it, i got mixed with all other features of the app, i believe the code must be put somewhere here :

this is my ExampleAdapter :

```
public class ExampleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ExampleAdapter.ExampleViewHolder>{
    private ArrayList<ExampleItem> mExampleList;

    public static class ExampleViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public ImageView mImageView;
        public TextView mTextView1;
        public TextView mTextView2;

        public ExampleViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            mTextView1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            mTextView2 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        }
    }

    public ExampleAdapter(ArrayList<ExampleItem> exampleList) {
        mExampleList = exampleList;
    }

    @Override
    public ExampleViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.example_item,
                parent, false);

        ExampleViewHolder evh = new ExampleViewHolder(v);
        return evh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ExampleViewHolder holder, int position) {
        ExampleItem currentItem = mExampleList.get(position);

        holder.mImageView.setImageResource(currentItem.getImageResource());
        holder.mTextView1.setText(currentItem.getText1());
        holder.mTextView2.setText(currentItem.getText2());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mExampleList.size();
    }

    public void filterList(ArrayList<ExampleItem> filteredList) {
        mExampleList = filteredList;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

really appreciate you guys, if you could help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this in your activity in which you have recyclerview

```
    rv= (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv);
rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
rv.addOnItemTouchListener(
                new RecyclerItemClickListener(this, rv ,new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
                        // do whatever


                    }
                    @Override public void onLongItemClick(View view, int position) {
                        // do whatever
                    }
                })
        );
```

Comment: i can't figure it out

Comment: take time for me to solved it, but it works. thank you

Answer (score 1):

Just edit `extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener`
and implement OnClick method ,edit as `public ExampleViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
itemView.setOnClickListener(this);`

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    }
```

Comment: i can't figure it out